# can you restore original functionality when using jest's automock?

Tags: jestjs, mocking

i would like to use automock, and then restore a single function to it's original value, test it, and then re-mock it. this seemed like a good way to prevent any functions from unexpectedly being called, but this doesn't seem possible.

or is there another way to whitelist individual functions to making assertions on them...

a VERY contrived example...

foo.js

```js
export function foo() {
  return 'FOO'
}
```

foo.test.js

```js
jest.enableAutomock()
import { foo } from 'foo.js'

foo.mockRestore()
expect(foo()).toBe('FOO')
```

Comment: If you need to get original implementation accidentally, use requireActual.

Comment: doesn't using requireActual just bypass automocking?

Comment: Yes. If most tests use mocked foo and you need to use real implementation in one test, it makes more sense to import another copy of a module for this test. Automocks replace original implementation, there's nothing they could be restored to. If you need them to behave differently, they aren't for you, use manual mocks.

Comment: that is exactly the info i needed! ty!... if you post an answer, i can mark it as the solution :)